# what is wrong here with my java script code?

Tags: javascript

everything was going fine ...problem starts form var per= 
it is not showing the result when I run it

```
<title> Java script 2</title>


<script  type="text/javascript">

var a= parseFloat( prompt("Enter X"));
var b= parseFloat( prompt ("Enter Y"));
var Area= ( 22 / 7 ) * a * b ;
var per= 2 * (22 / 7 ) (Math.sqrt((1 / 2)* Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)));
document.write("Area=" + Area);
document.write("Per=" + per);

 </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>  
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

there isn't any mathematical sign after (22 / 7 ). you should insert a product sign at this line:

```
   var per= 2 * (22 / 7 ) * (Math.sqrt((1 / 2)* Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing an arithmetic operation between `(22 / 7 ) (Math.sqrt((1 / 2)* Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)))`.

Answer (score 0):

You miss * in your formula :

```
var per= 2 * (22 / 7 )* (Math.sqrt((1 / 2)* Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2)));
```